# GetDateFormat with LOCALE_SSHORTDATE returns non-localized numbers

Tags: winapi, localization

I am running Windows 7 + Foreign language pack. (I've set the default locale to be the foreign language) I have a valid SYSTEMTIME struct and I am trying to build a localized date/time from it.

This is how I get the format string and then try to get the localized date

```
WCHAR pFmt[MAX_SIZE] = {0};
int localeinfo=GetLocaleInfo(localeID, LOCALE_SSHORTDATE, pFmt, sizeof(pFmt)/sizeof(TCHAR));
```

I've tried all the following

```
GetDateFormat(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, 0, &st, pFmt, formattedString, MAX_PATH);
GetDateFormat(LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, 0, &st, pFmt, formattedString, MAX_PATH);
GetDateFormat(localeinfo, 0, &st, pFmt, formattedString, MAX_PATH);
```

The string with the numbers does not get localized - In all the cases I always get formattedstring to be

```
pFmt            "dd/MM/yyyy"
formattedString "25/09/2012"      (I want this to be in the foreign language)
```

How can I get the formattedstring to have localized values for the numbers?

Comment: How exactly do you localize a number?

Comment: Install any foreign language pack - open the calendar. How are the numbers localized there? That's what I am looking to get.

Comment: The format string "dd/MM/yyyy" will always return a date formatted as numbers, and I think numbers will always be numbers, certainly in any European language pack they will be. You would need a format string that returns the month or day name rather than number to see a difference with localization.

Comment: @Jonathan Potter: True if you specify the format string yourself, but if you use the locale's default format you can easily see a difference. For example the short date format for en-US is month/day/year whereas for en-GB it's day/month/year.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: there are many written representations of digits.  [Arabic numerals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numerals) are the most widely used, but that wikipedia article has links to many other ways of writing numbers.

Answer (score 2):

If you want `GetDateFormat` to use the format that corresponds to whatever locale, then you should call it *without* a format string (4th parameter set to NULL).

For example try comparing formattedString after calling this:

```
LCID lcidEnUs = MAKELCID(MAKELANGID(LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US), SORT_DEFAULT);
GetDateFormat(lcidEnUs, 0, &st, NULL, formattedString, MAX_PATH);
```

And this:

```
LCID lcidFrFr = MAKELCID(MAKELANGID(LANG_FRENCH, SUBLANG_FRENCH), SORT_DEFAULT);
GetDateFormat(lcidFrFr, 0, &st, NULL, formattedString, MAX_PATH);
```